# How to install the latest version of rapids, without specifying the version number

Tags: nvidia, rapids

I would like to install the *latest* version of rapids without specifying the version number.

From here: https://rapids.ai/start.html

`conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge -c defaults rapids=0.15 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.1`

which works correctly. But if we drop the version number (0.15)

`conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge -c defaults rapids python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.1`

conda installs 0.01

if we remove rapids, nothing installs

How do I set this to get the latest release each time?

Answer (score 1):

From the great John Kirkham: please use `rapidsai::rapids`.  It will force the latest install for both `stable` or `nightlies`.

`conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge -c defaults rapidsai::rapids python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.1`